# Soundwaves and fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Hello first of all for everyone who is willing to help, I appreciate your help. I am trying to investigate the Fourier Transform and I decided to investigate sound waves. I have a sinusodial wave with known formula which is consisted of 3 seperate sinusodial waves with known formulas. Frequencies and amplitudes of these sound waves are known. Using Fourier Transform I am trying to show that the result of the transform will give me the frequencies I have entered. Before proceeding to my question I should state that I am an high school student which in the paper I am not allowed to go beyond my syllabus, only just a little bit. Here are my questions;

1. Is it pointless to do something like this given that I already know the frequencies? The point of the paper is that fourier transform can see the frequencies of a random wave so I am trying to prove that it can do this. But I am not sure whether it is pointless or not.
2. If it is not pointless and it is possible how can I do it?